# <nav> list element disappear when I resize windows

Tags: html, css

**Update:**
CSS File: http://pastebin.com/v9sQPzez
HTML file: http://pastebin.com/pA9eMQnT

I am having trouble with my `<nav>` element in css.

I have created the navigation menu with four buttons using this css,

```
nav{
    background: #000000;
    height: 120px;
    width:100%;
}


nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px; 
    text-align: center;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 20px 40px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.80em;
    border: none;
    color: #000;
}

nav a:hover, nav .current a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav .current a {
    background: #008C9A;
}
```

The problem is, when I resize the windows the right most buttons disappear instead of showing the horizontal scroll bar as shown in the image below,

[image]

and when I resize the chrome windows,

[image]

Why my browser isn't showing the horizontal scroll bar and removing the buttons from the navigation menu ?

Comment: The horizontal bar I don't know, but I don't think he 'removes' your nav items, they just are 'out of screen'. If you want to make your website responsive fast and easy use a framework like bootstrap or Skeleton if you want a minimal one.

Comment: There might be `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` or `<html>`

Comment: if you past your URL, it will be easy to find the exact problem by inspect element

Comment: actually there is no `overflow` used in my entire ccss

Comment: @Ajith, I have added the urls in the question, please see the updated question.

Comment: @Ajith - Stackoverflow prefers it if you **don't** have links to the problem page.  Stackoverflow acts as a resource for future readers, and linking to a page that would eventually (you hope) be fixed would not be helpful to those readers.  That is why we always ask for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with code posted into the original question

Comment: Nothing disappear, last <li> is hidden by <section>. remove `height: 90px;` from <nav> to see it.If you really want a fix height consider adding `overflow-y: auto;` on <nav> to show scroll bar.

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/poignant_benjamin/kqfxLvda/

Answer (score 0):

you better set min-width for body tag, something like

```
body{
    min-width: 720px; /* or what ever you want */
    ...
}
```

```css
body {
    min-width: 720px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #363636;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12pt;
 font-weight: 300;
}


h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

p {
 line-height: 190%;
}


a {
 color: #171717;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}



/*********************************************************************************/
/* List Styles                                                                   */
/*********************************************************************************/

 ul.style1
 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
 }
 
 ul.style1 li
 {
  border-top: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
  padding: 0.80em 0;
 }
 
 ul.style1 li:first-child
 {
  border-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
 }

 ul.style2
 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
 }
 
 ul.style2 li
 {
  border-top: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
  padding: 0.80em 0;
 }
 
 ul.style2 li:first-child
 {
  border-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
 }



/*********************************************************************************/
/* Heading Titles                                                                */
/*********************************************************************************/


#container {
 width: 100%;
 /* setting the left/right width to auto will center the content */
 margin: 0px auto;
 background: #FFFFFF ;
 padding:10px 0px;
 }

#container h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.20em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #00AABB;
 }
 




/* --------------------- 
   for Header area
--------------------- */

header
{
 background: #848484;
 text-align: center;
}


header h1{
  letter-spacing: 0.0em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1.1em 0;
 }

 
header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #81BEF7;
 }
 
header a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #81BEF7;
 }



nav{
 background: #00AABB;
 height: 90px;
 width:100%;
}


nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 35px 0px 0px 0px; /* top right bottom left */
 text-align: center;
}

nav li {
 display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
 display: inline-block;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 padding: 20px 40px; /* top/bottom and right/left */
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.80em;
 border: none;
 color: #FFF;
}

nav a:hover, nav .current a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav .current a {
 background: #008C9A;
}

/** PAGE */





/*********************************************************************************/
/* footer                                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

footer{
 padding: 1em 0em;
 text-align: center;
 background: #424242;
 /*position:absolute;*/
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
 }
 
footer p{
 letter-spacing: 0.20em;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.80em;
 color: #6F6F6F;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Widget Standards</title>
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>


 <header>
  <h1><a href="index.html">Test</a></h1>
 </header>
  
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li class="current"><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
  
 <section id="container">
  <h2>Integer sit amet aliquet</h2>
  <p>This is <strong>Retention</strong>, a free, fully standards-compliant CSS template designed by <a href="http://templated.co" rel="nofollow">TEMPLATED</a>. The photos in this template are from <a href="http://fotogrph.com/"> Fotogrph</a>. This free template is released under the <a href="http://templated.co/license">Creative Commons Attribution</a> license, so you're pretty much free to do whatever you want with it (even use it commercially) provided you give us credit for it. Have fun :) </p>
  <p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam pede erat, porta eu, lobortis eget, tempus et, tellus. Etiam neque. Vivamus consequat lorem at nisl. Nullam non wisi a sem semper eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. Duis pretium velit ac mauris. Proin eu wisi suscipit nulla suscipit interdum. Aenean lectus lorem, imperdiet at, ultrices eget, ornare et, wisi. Pellentesque adipiscing purus ac magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.  Nullam non wisi a sem semper eleifend. Donec mattis libero eget urna. </p>
 </section>


  
 <footer>
  <p>&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved.</p>
 </footer>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the width of nav bar equal to 100%. Set its width in pixels you want to set. Replace nav code with this one and check again.

```
nav{
    background: #000000;
    height: 120px;
    width: 800px; // here set width whichever you want
}
```

Comment: How will this help at all? Why would you want to use a specific width INSTEAD of a responsive, percentage based width?

Comment: As according to question, user wants to display horizontal scroll bar.. Setting with in pixels instead of percentage will give the required solution.

Comment: I don't think applying to the nav bar is the solution though, as you can see the page is actually responsive to an extent (the text wraps onto the next line). the better solution would be to change the layout of the menu, keep it at 100% width, but make the items blocks, or add overflow to the nav.

Comment: Well, i am agree with you. No doubt in that. But i just gave the answer as according to the requirement in the question. For the rest of the things to be the best, user must have to clearly specify what he wants. I thought @Riley have to modify his question a bit then.